# Getting sprites to move on their own in XNA

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

In my code, I am attempting to move three sprites on the X axis at one direction and speed. However, when I wrote the code in my class, it compiled fine without errors, but when the game started, the sprites that I wanted to move do not move at all. They just sit there. Code below:

```
                   class Enemy : EnemySprite
{
    const string ENEMY_ASSETNAME = "BadguyLeft";
    const int START_POSITION_X1 = 350;
    const int START_POSITION_X2 = 600;
    const int START_POSITION_X3 = 750;
    const int START_POSITION_Y = 415;
    const int MOVE_LEFT = -1;
    int WizardSpeed = 160;

    enum State
    {
        Walking
    }
```

The real issue is below:

```
               public void LoadContent(ContentManager theContentManager)
    {

        base.LoadContent(theContentManager, ENEMY_ASSETNAME);
    }

    public void Update(GameTime theGameTime)
    {
        //KeyboardState aCurrentKeyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();

        //UpdateMovement(aCurrentKeyboardState);

        //mPreviousKeyboardState = aCurrentKeyboardState;
        Position[0] = new Vector2(START_POSITION_X1, START_POSITION_Y);
        Position[1] = new Vector2(START_POSITION_X2, START_POSITION_Y);
        Position[2] = new Vector2(START_POSITION_X3, START_POSITION_Y);

        base.Update(theGameTime, mSpeed, mDirection);
    }

    private void UpdateMovement(KeyboardState aCurrentKeyboardState)
    {
        //int positionTracker = START_POSITION_X3;

        if (mCurrentState == State.Walking)
        {
            mSpeed = Vector2.Zero;
            mDirection = Vector2.Zero;


          for (int i = 0; i < Position.Count(); i++) 
            if (mCurrentState == State.Walking)
            {
                mSpeed.X = WizardSpeed;
                mDirection.X = MOVE_LEFT;
            }




        }
```

Comment: It looks like your call to UpdateMovement is commented out, and the positions are being re-initialized at the start positions. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: The call isn't needed, as Keyboard inputs are not a factor. About this re-initialized thing, could you care to explain this further please?

Comment: I'm assuming in the void Update method you'll need to update the X/Y variables of the enemies in some way. Usually this is done by an AI engine. You'll use those X/Y variables for updating the Position array in the void Update method.

Comment: Do you know where I could get a AI engine? I thought I wouldn't need one for this case, since I'm just telling the sprites to move in a very basic manner, just at the same time.

Comment: Hello? Are you still there?

Comment: Not saying it has to be an AI engine, but you need to update the X/Y chords of the enemies.

Answer (score 1):

You are simply never actually changing the position of the sprite.

You're update method is where the movement should (typically) take place.

It would look something like this:

```
//this will move an object to the left
Vector2 speed = new Vector2(-10, 0);
public void Update(GameTime theGameTime)
{
    //this will add the speed of the sprite to its position
    //making it move
    Position[0] += speed;
    Position[1] += speed;
    Position[2] += speed;

    base.Update(theGameTime, mSpeed, mDirection);
}
```